# Reactive Caching of HTTP Service

Tags: angular, caching, rxjs, rxjs5

I am using RsJS 5 (5.0.1) to cache in Angular 2. It works well.

The meat of the caching function is:

```
const observable = Observable.defer(
    () => actualFn().do(() => this.console.log('CACHE MISS', cacheKey))
  )
  .publishReplay(1, this.RECACHE_INTERVAL)
  .refCount().take(1)
  .do(() => this.console.log('CACHE HIT', cacheKey));
```

The `actualFn` is the `this.http.get('/some/resource')`.

Like I say, this is working perfectly for me. The cache is returned from the observable for duration of the `RECACHE_INTERVAL`. If a request is made after that interval, the `actualFn()` will be called.

What I am trying to figure out is when the `RECACHE_INTERVAL` expires and the `actualFn()` is called — how to return the last value. There is a space of time between when the `RECACHE_INTERVAL` expires and the `actualFn()` is replayed that the observable doesn't return a value. I would like to get rid of that gap in time and always return the last value.

I could use a side effect and store the last good value call `.next(lastValue)` while waiting for the HTTP response to return, but this seems naive. I would like to use a "RxJS" way, a pure function solution — if possible.

Answer (score 3):

Almost any complicated logic quickly goes out of control if you use plain `rxjs`. I would rather implement custom `cache` operator from scratch, you can use this [gist](https://gist.github.com/robwormald/19dea0c70a6e01aadced6731aed4f9f7) as an example.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated answer:**

If always want to use the previous value while a new request is being made then can put another subject in the chain which keeps the most recent value.

You can then repeat the value so it is possible to tell if it came from the cache or not. The subscriber can then filter out the cached values if they are not interested in those.

```js
// Take values while they pass the predicate, then return one more
// i.e also return the first value which returned false
const takeWhileInclusive = predicate => src =>
  src
  .flatMap(v => Observable.from([v, v]))
  .takeWhile((v, index) =>
     index % 2 === 0 ? true : predicate(v, index)
  )
  .filter((v, index) => index % 2 !== 1);

// Source observable will still push its values into the subject
// even after the subscriber unsubscribes
const keepHot = subject => src =>
  Observable.create(subscriber => {
    src.subscribe(subject);

    return subject.subscribe(subscriber);
  });

const cachedRequest = request
   // Subjects below only store the most recent value
   // so make sure most recent is marked as 'fromCache'
  .flatMap(v => Observable.from([
     {fromCache: false, value: v},
     {fromCache: true, value: v}
   ]))
   // Never complete subject
  .concat(Observable.never())
   // backup cache while new request is in progress
  .let(keepHot(new ReplaySubject(1)))
   // main cache with expiry time
  .let(keepHot(new ReplaySubject(1, this.RECACHE_INTERVAL)))
  .publish()
  .refCount()
  .let(takeWhileInclusive(v => v.fromCache));

  // Cache will be re-filled by request when there is another subscription after RECACHE_INTERVAL
  // Subscribers will get the most recent cached value first then an updated value
```

https://acutmore.jsbin.com/kekevib/8/edit?js,console

**Original answer:**

Instead of setting a window size on the replaySubject - you could change the source observable to repeat after a delay.

```js
const observable = Observable.defer(
    () => actualFn().do(() => this.console.log('CACHE MISS', cacheKey))
  )
  .repeatWhen(_ => _.delay(this.RECACHE_INTERVAL))
  .publishReplay(1)
  .refCount()
  .take(1)
  .do(() => this.console.log('CACHE HIT', cacheKey));
```

The `repeatWhen` operator requires RxJs-beta12 or higher
https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#500-beta12-2016-09-09

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this is very good. There are two issues: I need to remove the `.take(1)` operator from the chain, otherwise it will never make a second HTTP request. The second problem is that I would like the recache to be triggered when another subsribe() is called after the RECACHE_INTERVAL -- rather than every RECACHE_INTERVAL.

Comment: @Martin I have updated my answer so that requests are only made when another subscriber subscribes after RECACHE_INTERVAL. Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

See this demo: https://jsbin.com/todude/10/edit?js,console

Notice that I'm trying to get cached results at `1200ms` when the case is invalidated and then at `1300ms` when the previous request is still pending (it takes `200ms`). Both results are received as they should.

This happens because when you subscribe and the `publishReplay()` doesn't contain any valid value it won't emit anything and won't complete immediately (thanks to `take(1)`) so it needs to subscribe to its source which makes the HTTP requests (this in fact happens in `refCount()`).

Then the second subscriber won't receive anything as well and will be added to the array of observers in `publishReplay()`. It won't make another subscription because it's already subscribed to its source (`refCount()`) and is waiting for response.

So the situation you're describing shouldn't happen I think. Eventually make a demo that demonstrates your problem.

**EDIT**:

**Emitting both invalidated item and fresh items**

The following example shows a little different functionality than the linked example. If the cached response is invalidated it'll be emitted anyway and then it receives also the new value. This means the subscriber receives one or two values:

- 1 value: The cached value
- 2 values: The invalidated cached value and then new a fresh value that'll be cached from now on.

The code could look like the following:

```
let counter = 1;
const RECACHE_INTERVAL = 1000;

function mockDataFetch() {
  return Observable.of(counter++)
    .delay(200);
}

let source = Observable.defer(() => {
  const now = (new Date()).getTime();

  return mockDataFetch()
    .map(response => {
      return {
        'timestamp': now,
        'response': response,
      };
    });
});

let updateRequest = source
  .publishReplay(1)
  .refCount()
  .concatMap(value => {
    if (value.timestamp + RECACHE_INTERVAL > (new Date()).getTime()) {
      return Observable.from([value.response, null]);
    } else {
      return Observable.of(value.response);
    }
  })
  .takeWhile(value => value);


setTimeout(() => updateRequest.subscribe(val => console.log("Response 0:", val)), 0);
setTimeout(() => updateRequest.subscribe(val => console.log("Response 50:", val)), 50);
setTimeout(() => updateRequest.subscribe(val => console.log("Response 200:", val)), 200);
setTimeout(() => updateRequest.subscribe(val => console.log("Response 1200:", val)), 1200);
setTimeout(() => updateRequest.subscribe(val => console.log("Response 1300:", val)), 1300);
setTimeout(() => updateRequest.subscribe(val => console.log("Response 1500:", val)), 1500);
setTimeout(() => updateRequest.subscribe(val => console.log("Response 3500:", val)), 3500);
```

See live demo: https://jsbin.com/ketemi/2/edit?js,console

This prints to console the following output:

```
Response 0: 1
Response 50: 1
Response 200: 1
Response 1200: 1
Response 1300: 1
Response 1200: 2
Response 1300: 2
Response 1500: 2
Response 3500: 2
Response 3500: 3
```

Notice `1200` and `1300` received first the old cached value `1` immediately and then another value with the fresh `2`  value.
On the other hand `1500` received only the new value because `2` is already cached and is valid.

The most confusing thing is probably why am I using `concatMap().takeWhile()`. This is because I need to make sure that the fresh response (not the invalidated) is the last value before sending complete notification and there's probably no operator for that (neither `first()` nor `takeWhile()` are applicable for this use-case).

**Emitting only the current item without waiting for refresh**

Yet another use-case could be when we want to emit only the cached value while not waiting for fresh response from the HTTP request.

```
let counter = 1;
const RECACHE_INTERVAL = 1000;

function mockDataFetch() {
  return Observable.of(counter++)
    .delay(200);
}

let source = Observable.defer(() => {
  const now = (new Date()).getTime();

  return mockDataFetch()
    .map(response => {
      return {
        'timestamp': now,
        'response': response,
      };
    });
});

let updateRequest = source
  .publishReplay(1)
  .refCount()
  .concatMap((value, i) => {
    if (i === 0) {
      if (value.timestamp + RECACHE_INTERVAL > (new Date()).getTime()) { // is cached item valid?
        return Observable.from([value.response, null]);
      } else {
        return Observable.of(value.response);
      }
    }
    return Observable.of(null);
  })
  .takeWhile(value => value);


setTimeout(() => updateRequest.subscribe(val => console.log("Response 0:", val)), 0);
setTimeout(() => updateRequest.subscribe(val => console.log("Response 50:", val)), 50);
setTimeout(() => updateRequest.subscribe(val => console.log("Response 200:", val)), 200);
setTimeout(() => updateRequest.subscribe(val => console.log("Response 1200:", val)), 1200);
setTimeout(() => updateRequest.subscribe(val => console.log("Response 1300:", val)), 1300);
setTimeout(() => updateRequest.subscribe(val => console.log("Response 1500:", val)), 1500);
setTimeout(() => updateRequest.subscribe(val => console.log("Response 3500:", val)), 3500);
setTimeout(() => updateRequest.subscribe(val => console.log("Response 3800:", val)), 3800);
```

See live demo: https://jsbin.com/kebapu/2/edit?js,console

This example prints to console:

```
Response 0: 1
Response 50: 1
Response 200: 1
Response 1200: 1
Response 1300: 1
Response 1500: 2
Response 3500: 2
Response 3800: 3
```

Notice that both `1200` and `1300` receive value `1` because that's the cached value even though it's invalid now. The first call at `1200` just spawns a new HTTP request without waiting for its response and emits only the cached value. Then at `1500` the fresh value is cached so it's just reemitted. The same applies at `3500` and `3800`.

Note, that the subscriber at `1200` will receive the `next` notification immediately but the `complete` notification will be sent only after the HTTP request has finished. We need to wait because if we sent `complete` right after `next` it'd make the chain to dispose its disposables which should also cancel the HTTP request (which is what we definitely don't want to do).

Comment: Martin, thanks for the answer. I completely get how my current implementation works. What I am unclear about is the last sentence -- is the 'situation' are you referring to my desired behavior or my existing working behavior?

Comment: @Martin My bad, I wanted to write "should never happen". I don't think you can have an empty window where your subscribers don't receive anything.

Comment: OK I see -- I was not specific enough in my question. The 'gap' occurs when a new observer subscribes after the RECACHE_INTERVAL. Ill update the question to clarify. Thank for that.

Comment: @Martin Isn't this exactly what I'm describing and showing in https://jsbin.com/todude/10/edit?js,console ?

Comment: unfortnatly no that shows the existing 'working' behavior, with the 'gap' in time I describe. Add `console.log('we get here')` inside your `setTimeout()`s just before the `updateRequest.subscribe(...)` and you will see the gap. Thanks again.

Comment: @Martin You mean like this? https://jsbin.com/todude/11/edit?js,console

Comment: this better illustrates the issue: https://jsbin.com/wajetuxoga/edit?js,console 1300 gets the gap most of the time. I have seen a few random runs where 1200 gets it.

Comment: @Martin That's correct behavior. You don't lose any value because any new subscriber will wait until the new value is ready.

Comment: @Martin Btw, see my update, maybe this is what you're going for.